# Add row to order totals in Order Admin View

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, sales-order

I would like to add a row with the sum of a custom column values to the order view totals.

If you look at the image you can understand better what I mean.

[image: order grid view]

The problem is that I found the .phtml file to edit but I don't know how to add a method to make a Sum of the values of the "PREZZO LISTINO" column.

PREZZO LISTINO column is custom column made using a custom attribute value from products. It is the "cost" of the good (is how much I pay it from the wholesaler).

Comment: What is that column price source ? I'm not italian speaker, so you will have to clarify things in english =) I thought that was special price, is that it ?

Comment: the column "PREZZO LISTINO" is the cost column. I mean is how much i pay the goods from the wholesaler. I get that values from a custom item attribute.

Comment: Can you show how you relate this custom item attribute to an order ? Is it an attribute you used for configurable product creation ? Are these products  configurable ?

Comment: I've already know how to add a line in subtotals, but we need to find how to pull the subtotal value.